# Why do we use self clause while creating a method in class object in Python?

Tags: python, class

```py
class name:
     def method_1(self, Def):
         self.Def = DEF
     def method_2(self):
          return self.Def
```

why the self clause at every method definition? I couldn't understand it’s purpose in the code and clarifying through websites didn't work.

Comment: See [explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2709821/what-is-the-purpose-of-the-self-parameter-why-is-it-needed#2709832)

Answer (score 2):

Because that's the way Python is defined. When you write `obj.f()`, Python will call `f` with `obj` as the first argument. Unlike a lot of other object-oriented languages, like C++ or Java, this first argument is not implicit -- you must declare it in the function definition, and use it anytime you want to access a member of the object -- if the object has another function `g()`, then to call it from `obj.f()`, you would have to write `self.g()`, rather than just `g()`, as is the case in languages like C++ or Java.

The name `self` is just a convention. You could call it anything you want: `toto` or `foo`, for example, and the code would work just as well, although it sure would confuse any readers (so don't do it).

Answer (score 0):

self just means "the object that is running the function", for example,
if i use the function `[].append`, then `[]` would be self, and the function is `append`. so in code, it would look like

```
class list:
    def append(self, new):
        ...
```

in your case:

```
class name: 
    def method1(self,Def): self.Def = Def
    def method2(self): return self.Def
```

if i were to use your code, then it would be like this:

```
foo = name()
foo.method1("example")
foo.method2() # returns "example"
```

as you can see, self just means that i am using the same object for multiple reasons, if i only wanted to use self for 1 purpose, then i would use a normal function or a `@staticmethod`

Comment: That's not quite right. `self` doesn't really mean anything -- it's just the name of the first argument, and the use of `self`, rather than `toto` or `foo`, is just convention. (The fact that it's the first argument **is** significant, though.)

Comment: @JamesKanze true, but this guy is a beginner, explaining that is a bit more complicated than to just explain using the naming convention, so i decided to not do that.